# allowsEdgeAntialiasing not working on real device

Tags: ios, uikit

```
layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
```

The result on simulator is perfect, But it's not working on real device and edges are not smooth as expected.

I've tried adding `UIViewEdgeAntialiasing: YES` to `plist.info`, too.

Any idea about what the problem can be?

---

Edit:

On simulator:
[image: on simulator]

On real device:
[image: on real device]

And my test code is:

```
class MyCircleView: UIView {
@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}
@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
    }
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

override open func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setup()
}

override open func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
    layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
    layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
}

}
```

Comment: did you tried clip to bounds?

Comment: show us the difference by adding both screenshots.

Comment: @RatulSharker Added!

Comment: I encounter this on my iphone7 ios12, any solution on this?

Comment: @LeiKan unfortunately, not yet :)